# Can i ask "to be considered" for another office of same company?

Tags: interviewing

I have applied for a software tester position in a big company in Hamburg. The Hamburg office has invited me for an HR interview.

I figured out, there is an identical position for the company in Berlin as well.
The requirements for the position in Berlin are 100% equal to Hamburg's position. It is just different cities. But, for some personal reasons, ***I prefer to work in Berlin rather than Hamburg.*** I just think, Berlin is more international, and more dynamic in comparison to Hamburg.

I am wondering:

1. Can I ask in my HR interview (with **Hamburg**) to be considered for **Berlin**?
2. If I ask this, how would it effect the interviewer, and the result of interview?
3. Is personal preference good reason to work in another city, or I should provide stronger reasons? I think, the first reaction of HR will be `why do you prefer Berlin?`

Comment: Why would this be a problem? Why do people have such a difficult time asking for what they want? Why would the company have a problem with you asking this? If you would prefer to work in Berlin then tell them that you would prefer to work in Berlin. It's that simple.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I ask in my HR interview (with Hamburg) to be considered for Berlin?

Yes you can, but it might be two different hiring managers for the two roles. You have to consider the situation that Hamburg may want you, but Berlin doesn't. If you need a job badly, I would tell the HR representative that you would like to be considered for both locations and you have a strong preference for Berlin.

> If I ask such this, how would it affect the interviewer, and the result of interview?

If the offices are separate, they may ask you to apply to Berlin position separately. Some companies don't allow multiple groups to interview the same person, which would you need to retract your application to the Hamburg position.

> Is personal preference good reason to work in another city, or i should provide stronger reasons?

Yes, personal preference is a perfectly good reason to like one city over another. If HR were to ask "Why do you prefer Berlin?", you could again state it's just a personal preference being familiar with both cities. If Hamburg office is desperate for people they may try to convince you to apply for them.

Comment: i wish to know your point of view about the third question as well

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara I added a response to the last question too!

Comment: Yes, i noted. I appreciate your advises.